# How do I enable the visual menu when changing language inputs?

Tags: macos

I saw this enabled on my friends Lion MBA, but I couldn't find a way to enable it on my Mountian Lion MBP. Anyone have any ideas?

[image: When changing languages]

Comment: Are you able to switch keyboards via apple/command plus space?  If not, you may need to deactivate that shortcut in system preferences/spotlight.  Once the shortcut can be used for changing keyboards, the list normally appears if you hold space key for a bit.

Comment: I changed the hotkey to option + shift + space. I have the same setup on both computers.

Comment: I thought the visual menu would only work when you use the apple/command plus space hotkey.  But if it works on the other computer with option/shift/space, I don't know why it would not work on this one.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something I'm missing, but it seems to be shown only for the shortcut for selecting the previous input source (⌘␣ by default). If the shortcut is an F-key, it is only shown if you hold the key and only for a split second.